# Differential equation $6x^3(2ydx-3xdy)+y^4(-3ydx+2xdy)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am struggling with this differential equation.
$$6x^3(2ydx-3xdy)+y^4(-3ydx+2xdy)=0$$

I was trying to separate variables and many other things. It didn't help.  Do you have any tips?

Comment: First thing you'd usually do in this situation is write the equation in the form $N(x, y)dx+M(x, y)dy = 0$.

Comment: Then you may want to check whether $\frac{\partial N}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}$ holds.

Comment: I was trying. It does not. The integrating factor does not help too.

Answer (score 2):

$$6x^3(2ydx-3xdy)+y^4(-3ydx+2xdy)=0$$
You should try an integrating factor on the form:
$$\mu(x,y)=x^ay^b$$

---

Here is a more intuitive approach:

Multiply by $y^2x$:
$$6x^3(2y^3xdx-3x^2y^2dy)+y^4(-3y^3xdx+2x^2y^2dy)=0$$
$$6x^3(y^3dx^2-x^2dy^3)+\dfrac {y^5}x(-3y^2x^2dx+2x^3ydy)=0$$
$$6x^3(y^3dx^2-x^2dy^3)+\dfrac {y^5}x(-y^2dx^3+x^3dy^2)=0$$
$$6yd\left(\dfrac {x^2}{y^3}\right)+x^2 d\left( \dfrac {y^2}{x^3}\right)=0$$
Multiply by $y/x^3$:
$$\dfrac {6y^2}{x^3}d\left(\dfrac {x^2}{y^3}\right)+\dfrac yx d\left( \dfrac {y^2}{x^3}\right)=0$$
$$6udv+\left (\dfrac {u}{v} \right)^{1/5}du=0$$
Where $u=\dfrac {y^2}{x^3}$ and $v=\dfrac {x^2}{y^3}$

The differential equation is now separable. Separate and integrate.